# Mac OS terminal extension/plugin

Tags: macos, plugins, terminal

What names have these extension for terminal - first line(path) and last line? [searching plugin in left part of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6fEE.png) 

For clarify: 
first extension/plugin for showing path(in image):
 D/combineReducer.js D/document.rb (its look like showing path in terminal tab)
second(last line):
Normal    Document/document.rb                                              ruby   utf-8[unix]   82%   245:30

Comment: Can you clarify. And instead of posting an image please copy-paste the revelent code directly in the question

Comment: These are not terminal plugins. It look like it's VIM with a JS and a ruby file opened.

Answer (score 0):

Its VIM plugins
Example where can it be founded are:
https://vimawesome.com
http://vim-bootstrap.com

tab are new feature from VIM 7

all is setup in .vimrc file